# Set Keyboard Layout to my language

Tags: raspbian, keyboard

I have this keyboard: http://trust.com/products/product.aspx?artnr=17603 and i cant configure it with Raspbian. I run `rasp-config` and went to `configure_keyboard`, selected a generic 105-key keyboard and set the language to Portuguese (my language) and it is all messy!
Help is appreciated

Comment: It is easy in the GUI but unpredictable, as I ask here:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66083/how-can-i-force-raspbian-stay-set-to-the-us-keyboard

Answer (score 2):

Check your /etc/default/keyboard for your layout.

```
cat /etc/default/keyboard | grep LAYOUT
```

If it's anything other than your language code, let's change it. We'll have to do that as root, so:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard
```

and change the value to what you need it to be. I use dvorak, so if I were on Debian mine would look like:

```
XKBLAYOUT="dvorak"
```

Yours will just be your language code, though. Just to make sure, also, it'd probably be good measure to check your locale. Can you also check the result of:

```
env | grep LANG
```

Comment: This is half an answer.  Good info, but how do I make it a regular US Keyboard, whether 104-key or the tiny one?  They are both wired.