# How can I force Raspbian stay set to the US keyboard? Americanizing the Pi

Tags: raspbian, keyboard, settings

I have several Rpi3Bs and for the most part they work well.

But one of them insists on changing the USB keyboard type to the UK keyboard.

I fix it after a reboot by going into Menu..Preferences..Keyboard..Keyboard and Mouse..Keyboard Layout

It would me nice if I could figure out where this setting is stored and mark the file read-only or something.  The one thing I have figured out is that it is not set in /boot/config.txt

In Raspi-config, localization is set for both gb and en_US - not sure why.

So the question is in the title:  How can I force Raspbian stay set to the US keyboard?

Comment: I would have hoped that would have worked.  Have a look at https://superuser.com/questions/646425/permanently-change-default-language-and-keyboard-settings-what-am-i-missing

Comment: I found that in /etc/default/keyboard it was set to "gb" so I changed it to "en_US" and it survived a reboot.  ..so I did a sudo chmod -w keyboard. 
 Thank you for the tip, @joan

Comment: This  isn't daily but keeps happening.  Clue:  It is the only Pi where I have an actual keyboard and screen on it.  In /etc/default/keyboard it is back to XBLAYOUT=gb"  - perhaps I should simply make the file read-only once it is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting the keyboard layout in

```
Menu
Preferences
Mouse and Keyboard Settings
Keyboard tab
Keyboard Layout
Pick United States on the left,
then English (US) on the right.
OK, OK
```

The keyboard is set properly.

Then the rest of the locale stuff is set by using this:

```
sudo raspi-config
Localization options
```

...is the same as running

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

As per this article:

[“Americanizing” the Raspberry Pi](http://rohankapoor.com/2012/04/americanizing-the-raspberry-pi/)

**Make sure the gb localization is unchecked.**

Set the locale to be en_US.UTF-8 like so:

```
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
Spacebar to mark it with an asterisk
tab to OK then press Enter
```

> It will give you a confirmation page.
>
> **Make sure you look at it and that you are selected to en_US.UTF-8**

```
Once set, tab to OK and press enter.
```

After doing this, it will be set to persist through restarts.

One nice side-effect is that the date format will be mm/dd/yy

Comment: The “Americanizing” the Raspberry Pi - link is dead :-(

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can be solved with

#### Persistent configuration

A persistent keymap can be set in `/etc/vconsole.conf` which is read by systemd on start-up.

- The KEYMAPvariable is used for specifying the keymap. If the variable is empty or not set, the uk keymap is used as default value.

  - For example:

    `/etc/vconsole.conf
    KEYMAP=uk ...`
  - For convenience, localectl may be used to set console keymap.
    It will change the KEYMAP variable in /etc/vconsole.conf 

    `$ localectl set-keymap --no-
    convert keymap`
  - The `--no-convert` option can be used to prevent `localectl` from automatically changing the Xorg keymap to the nearest match. See `man localectl` for more information.

Comment: That file does not exist on my system.  There is no /etc/vcon* of any kind.

Comment: You might `cat /boot/os_config.json` and verify `"keyboard"` is set correctly.

Comment: And now it has happened again.  This time it was just a restart.    Switching the @ and " signs aren't that big of a problem, but the tilde turns into a weird sideways half-bracket.  This is getting old.  I can go into Preferences, Keyboard & Mouse, Keyboard, Keyboard layout, then set it back.   /boot/os_config.json has it set to gb. So I change it to us and reboot, only to find it set back to gb. --  I even did sudo chmod a-w os_config.json